# JSTL not generating JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, jsp, jstl

i am trying to write a API using JSP/JSTL to generate JSON output but its not working in am not able to figure out the problem. Here i am getting problem when using **C tag Library** for reading the array.Here is the code:

```
<%@ page import="java.lang.*,java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/abc" user="root"  password="xxx"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result" sql="SELECT countries_name,countries_iso_code_2  FROM countries"/>

<json:object> 
    <json:object name="list">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <json:object items="countries">
            <json:property name="Country" value="${row.countries_name}"/>
            <json:property name="iso" value="${row.countries_iso_code_2}"/>
        </json:object>
        </c:forEach>
  </json:object>
</json:object>
```

The Exception i am getting is as

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.ws.indexajson_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:178)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Please help me to rectify the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or errors? What's happening that isn't what you want?

Comment: i've updated your question and removed `////problem starts here` comment. note that you shouldn't direct users to a specific point in your code, as it would make their assumptions prejudice.

Comment: edit your question to include this exception. and **please** read the [FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @EliranMalka It's arguable in this case, but the general statement "You shouldn't direct users to a specific point in your code" is totally incorrect. If there's an error in the code, and they know which line is causing it but not **why**, it's a good idea to tell people which line that is.

Comment: Thanks both of you i have removed that line from there.

Comment: Sumant we're now on a free discussion here :) @AnthonyGrist i agree, assuming that line is the root of the exception's stack-trace or the like. i disagree when it's only a vague assumption (that's not a better assumption than any other user's) - it's likely that users will attack the problem from a different angle, thus resulting in **more coverage** and more likely to resolve the problem. this, of course, can be extended to a long debate.. anyhow i appreciate your opinion on this, thank you.

Comment: Thanks both of you for showing me the path to correct the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have solved it. i just removed **C Tag Library**  changed json generating code as

```
<json:object> 
    <json:object name="list">
        <json:array name="countries" var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <json:object>
                <json:property name="Country" value="${row.countries_name}"/>
                <json:property name="iso" value="${row.countries_iso_code_2}"/>
            </json:object>
        </json:array>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

and it works. i got the problem was my array syntax.